# How to use RIJNDAEL encryption with Laravel 7 / PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, rijndael

I need to encrypt some .mp3 files with RIJNDAEL algorythm, i am trying to implementing it with the latest laravel version and no success so far.

What i am doing:

**app.php**

```
'cipher' => 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128',
```

Added to **composer.json**:

```
"ext-mcrypt": "*"
```

With those changes i get the following error:

```
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.
```

What more should/have to do ? I already did some research but no solution so far.

Thanks

Comment: do you have the mcrypt PHP extension?

Comment: Forget about the non-standard RIJNDAEL. Use AES that is the NIST standard.

Comment: mcrypt is insecure. Use one of the other libraries that replaced it (such as the OpenSSL based one). Besides that `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is RIJNDAEL with a block cipher of 128 bits. It is also known as AES as long as you use key sizes of 128, 192 or 256 bits (for AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256 respectively).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcrypt is insecure. Use one of the other libraries that replaced it (such as the OpenSSL based one).

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is Rijndael with a block cipher of 128 bits. **It is also known as AES** as long as you use key sizes of 128, 192 or 256 bits (for AES-128, AES-192 and AES-256 respectively).

So just use one of the supported ciphers that are indicated, and you're all set.